# Reactive extensions: splitting by starting object

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Say I have an Observable of ints: `obs = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 1 :: 3 :: 1 :: 1 :: 2`, and I want to accumulate series starting by a `1`, as follows:

`acc_obs = 1 + 2 + 3 :: 1 + 3 :: 1 :: 1 + 2` = `6 :: 4 :: 1 :: 3`.

How can I do that with reactive extensions?

I thought about using `obs.filter(i -> i == 1)` and use that with some kind of `buffer(bufferClosingSelector)`, but it seems like it has two issues:

- It doesn't work with cold observables
- If my `bufferClosingSelector` "closes" the buffer everytime it finds a `1`, I will have an offset of one and emit something like `1 :: 2 + 3 + 1 :: 3 + 1 :: 1`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved with an Subject and a Window, but it does not look that good. Please have a look:

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    //  1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 1 :: 3 :: 1 :: 1 :: 2

    Observable<Integer> just = Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2)).share();

    Subject<Integer> objectPublishSubject = PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

    just.doOnNext(objectPublishSubject::onNext)
            .window(() -> {
                return objectPublishSubject.takeUntil(integer -> integer == 1).takeLast(1);
            }).flatMap(integerObservable -> integerObservable.reduce((integer, integer2) -> {
        return integer + integer2;
    }).toObservable())
            .test().assertResult(6, 4, 1, 3);
}
```

Comment: So the Subject is a trick to use the same observable twice, right? How much of a hack is it? :D

Comment: Well, it is allowed to use an subject in doOnNext to store state. I do not know how good it is integrateable in your system because it is stateful. Just try it if it works for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look! Thanks!